# Catalog + Shopping cart rule, discounting wrong fields when applied

Tags: magento-1.7, shopping-cart-price-rules, catalog-price-rules

I currently have an issue where I have a catalog rule of 10% for a specific type of members A. Additionally, I have a shopping cart coupon of 100% off which applies to a product in it's own category: 387. However, it seems when there are instances where member A is trying to buy an item in category 387, initially the shopping cart coupon is applied (-$x) and the grand total should just be the shipping. However, the catalog rule takes the Original subtotal and discounts 10% and updates the grand total as 0.9*$x which is in correct as it should only show the shipping cost
I have set up the catalog rule as follows:

**rule info**

Customer group: A
Priority 2:

**conditions**

if Any of the conditions are true: category is not 387

**actions**

Apply: by % of orig price

discount amt: 10.00

enable disc to subprd: yes

Apply: by % of orig price

discount amt: 10.00

stop further rule process: no

I feel like my shopping cart rule is set almost correctly as the issue only occurrs when member A has a product that fits the 100% discount code in cart. Here is my shopping cart rule with priority 1:

**rule info**

customer grp : A

Specific coupon

**condition**

if All the cond are true:
 if an item found in cart w/ ALL cond true:
   category is 387

**action**

Apply (% of product price discount)

Discount amt: 100

Max Qty to discount : 1

Discount qty stp by x : 1

apply to ship amnt : no

free ship: no

stop further rules processing: no

Apply the rule only to cart items matching:
if ALL the cond are true:
category is 387

However, I am getting the following behavior:

[image]

Any help is much appreciated as Im new to this forum and new to Magento.

Answer (score 0):

Working on someone else's code, I tried not to modify existing items, but it turns out it was best to change the catalog rule to an auto applied (with no coupon code needed) shopping cart rule. As catalog rules apply price difference and saves in tables prior to shopping cart rules, converting catalog -> shopping allowed me to adjust priority properly